# Java Regex: word ending in 's' except specific words

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to find a regex.
I have this:

```
String regex_words_ended_s_in_singular_form = "\\b(anglais|francais)\\b";
```

Then, I want to delete the 's' at the end of all words except for "anglais" and "francais".

I tried this, but it doesn't work of course:

```
String temp = tweet.replaceAll( "(?!" + regex_words_ended_s_in_singular_form + ")" + "s\\b","");

while (!temp.equals(tweet)) {
    tweet = temp;
    temp = tweet.replaceAll( "(?!" + regex_words_ended_s_in_singular_form + ")" + "s\\b","");
}
tweet = temp;
```

Comment: So you just want a regex that finds any word ending in `s`?

Comment: can you please provide an input output example?

Answer (score 0):

To match any word ending in `s` but `anglais` and `francais` you may use

```
\b(?!(?:anglais|francais)\b)(\w*)s\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/18Mg95/3)

**Details**

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?!(?:anglais|francais)\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a whole word `anglais` or `francais` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(\w*)` - Group 1: zero or more word chars
- `s` - an `s`
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

In Java:

```
String res = s.replaceAll("\\b(?!(?:anglais|francais)\\b)(\\w*)s\\b", "$1");
```

Comment: I just want to delete the 's' at the end of each words of a text but not for anglais and francais.
Whith your solution, I just delete words and not only 's' :/

Comment: @GeoffreyGuettier Fixed.

Comment: Thank you a lot it works ! I just have a last question, do I need a loop because of the "|" ? What does "?:" mean ?

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work, it delete all the word instead of the 's' :(
maybe with this :


String res = s.replaceAll("\\b(?!(?:anglais|francais)\\b)(\\w*)s\\b", "$1$2");

Let me try...

Answer (score 0):

Your comment makes it sound like you just want to find words ending in 's'. If so, you could use something like this:

`[\S]+(s\b)` 
[regexr link](http://regexr.com/3ggoo)

Comment: No I dont want this. I want to delete the 's' at the end of a word except for "anglais" and "francais".